# Python Django Mezzanine install fail for Pillow package

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, python-imaging-library

I try to install Mezzanine
but it fail installing Pillow

python setup.py install return this error:

```
Processing Pillow-2.5.1.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-5pOzTp/Pillow-2.5.1/setup.cfg
Running Pillow-2.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-5pOzTp/Pillow-2.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-E2JGiB
warning: no files found matching '*.bdf' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.fli' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.icns' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.ico' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.pbm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.pil' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.ppm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.psd' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.tar' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.webp' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.xpm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Sane'
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Scripts'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'Tk'
Building using 4 processes
_imaging.c: In function ‘setup_module’:
_imaging.c:3575:37: error: ‘Z_RLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
PyModule_AddIntConstant(m, "RLE", Z_RLE);
                                 ^
_imaging.c:3575:37: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each     function it appears in
_imaging.c:3576:39: error: ‘Z_FIXED’ undeclared (first use in this function)
PyModule_AddIntConstant(m, "FIXED", Z_FIXED);
                                   ^
libImaging/Draw.c: In function ‘ImagingDrawWideLine’:
libImaging/Draw.c:603:9: warning: unused variable ‘vertices’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int vertices[4][2];
     ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o: File o directory non esistente
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

If I try to install using pip install mezzanine I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/franco/.virtualenvs/audace/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/franco/.virtualenvs/audace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/home/franco/.virtualenvs/audace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As you can see the problem is in installing Pillow requirements
I'm working with virtualenv

thanks

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the development libraries. For Ubuntu, this means you need to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential 
sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

---

This bug was fixed [12 days ago](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/790), so you might want to run `pip install -U pillow`, or `pip install git+https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git`

Comment: After development libraries installation, I have the same error

Comment: Please update your question and put the traceback you get when you do `pip install pillow`.

Comment: Hi already have build-dep python-imaging `Scelto "pillow" come pacchetto sorgente al posto di "python-imaging"
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 9 non aggiornati.`

Comment: I cannot solve the problem. I have the same error even if I use `pip install -U pillow`, or `pip install git+https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git`

Comment: Any suggestion? i remove all and istall again but the error is the same. Maybe I have to clean some library and try again...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions above about installing the development libraries. In the second command string, delete the first "libjpeg" so it looks like this:

```
    sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Afterwards, install pillow and you are done!